# How to train a neural network with X being 5d and y being 2d (padded)

Tags: keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, training-data, chess

I'm trying to train a neural network that mimics the chess playing style of a specific player.
The problem is that I can't train the model because of its shape. Maybe I need to make y.shape 1D because the shape of y_train should match the shape of the output layer. But then I think the model can't keep track of each game and each move. In addition the 245 and 14 dimensions seem to also be wrong to train a model. How can I implement the model so that it can learn or how would I need to modify the data in order to train the model and get a move as an output? I'm expecting the model to take in a board state and return 1 move/label

X shape  (24242, 245, 14, 8, 8)
numpy array containing 24242 games in numerical representation,
each game was padded to 245 moves,
each move consists of 14 8x8 boards (1 board for every type of piece (pawns, rooks, knights, bishops, queens, king) + 1 board showing every quare that is attacked on the board from white's perspective in numerical representation + same thing for the black pieces)

y shape (24242, 245)
1 list for every game(24242 in total) containing 245 elements each(padded with '0')  label encoded SAN but only the moves that the player I want to mimic has played during the game. first 3 games look like this:

```
(24242, 245)
[[3830 3956    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0...
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [4026 3961    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0...
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [3769 3711  715 3830   76 3958 3772 4024 4026 4051 3986 3873   58  225
   976 1065 1643 1702 3893   79 3917 1318  890    0    0    0    0    0 ...
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0    0    0]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Model:

```
def build_model(conv_size, conv_depth):
    board3d = layers.Input(shape=(max_len, 14, 8, 8))
    x = board3d
    for _ in range(conv_depth):
        x = layers.Conv2D(filters=conv_size, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(64, "relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dense(len(d), "sigmoid")(x) #len(d) = 4066 distinct labels
    return models.Model(inputs=board3d, outputs=x)


model = build_model(32, 4)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(5e-4), loss="categorical_crossentropy")
model.summary()



model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=5,
          epochs=1000,
          verbose=1,
          validation_split=0.1,
          callbacks=[callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="loss", patience=10),
                     callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="loss", patience=15, min_delta=0.0001)])
```

Output

```
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_9 (InputLayer)        [(None, 248, 14, 8, 8)]   0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_8 (Conv2D)           (None, 248, 14, 8, 32)    2336      
                                                                 
 conv2d_9 (Conv2D)           (None, 248, 14, 8, 32)    9248      
                                                                 
 conv2d_10 (Conv2D)          (None, 248, 14, 8, 32)    9248      
                                                                 
 conv2d_11 (Conv2D)          (None, 248, 14, 8, 32)    9248      
                                                                 
 flatten_2 (Flatten)         (None, 888832)            0         
                                                                 
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 64)                56885312  
                                                                 
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 4063)              264095    
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 57,179,487
Trainable params: 57,179,487
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/1000

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[151], line 23
     20 # Reshape y_train to match the output shape of the model
     21 y_train = y_train.reshape(y_train.shape[0], -1)
---> 23 model.fit(X_train, y_train,
     24           batch_size=5,
     25           epochs=1000,
     26           verbose=1,
     27           validation_split=0.1,
     28           callbacks=[callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="loss", patience=10),
     29                      callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="loss", patience=15, min_delta=0.0001)])

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
...
    File "C:\Users\ffgd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5633, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      res = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [5,4066] and labels shape [1225]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4291]
```

Sometimes I also get similar things to this Error message when I try to change the model:

#ValueError: Shapes (None, 245) and (None, 4066) are incompatible